# Поиск целых корней кубического уравнения по заданным коэффициентам

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, линейная-алгебра, реализация

Помогите решить (поделится идеей решения) данной задачи, не проходит 16 тест.

**Условие**

Напишите программу, которая будет искать все целые `X`, удовлетворяющие уравнению `A*X^3 + B*X^2 + C*X + D = 0`, где `A, B, C, D` – заданные целые коэффициенты.

**Входные данные**

Во входном файле `INPUT.TXT` записаны четыре целых числа: `A, B, C, D`. Все числа по модулю не превышают `2×10^9`.

**Выходные данные**

В выходной файл `OUTPUT.TXT` выведите сначала количество различных корней этого уравнения в целых числах, а затем сами корни в возрастающем порядке. Если уравнение имеет бесконечно много корней, то следует вывести в выходной файл одно число -1 (минус один).

Проверяющая система: [acmp.ru](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=257)

Мой код: https://pastebin.com/ajaexiek

Я ищу делители числа d и по ним отбираю корни, так же я рассмотрел все случаи когда коэффициенты равен(равны) нулю.

Код здесь:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
typedef long long ll;
vector <ll> s;
 
ll check(ll n, ll a, ll b, ll c, ll d){
    return (a*n*n*n+b*n*n+c*n+d);
}
 
void poisk(ll n, ll a, ll b, ll c, ll d){
    for (ll i = 1; i*i <= abs(n); i++){ 
        if (n % i == 0){                    
            if (check(i, a, b, c, d) == 0)
                s.push_back(i);
            if (check(n/i, a, b, c, d) == 0)
                s.push_back(n/i);
            if (check(-1*i, a, b, c, d) == 0)
                s.push_back(-1*i);
            if (check(-1*n/i, a, b, c, d) == 0)
                s.push_back(-1*n/i);
        }
    }
}
 
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
    ll a, b, c, d; 
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;    
    if (a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 0 and d == 0){
        cout << -1;
        return 0;
    }
    if (a != 0 and b!=0 and c==0 and d==0 or a == 0 and b == 0 and c != 0 and d == 0 or a == 0 and b != 0 and c == 0 and d == 0 or a != 0 and b == 0 and c == 0 and d == 0 or a != 0 and b == 0 and c != 0 and d == 0 or a!= 0 and b!=0 and c!=0 and d==0)
        s.push_back(0);
    if (a == 0 and b != 0 and c != 0 and d == 0 or a != 0 and b == 0 and c != 0 and d == 0 or a!= 0 and b!=0 and c!=0 and d==0)
        poisk(c, a, b, c, d);
    if (a != 0 and b!=0 and c==0 and d==0)  
        poisk(b, a, b, c, d);   
    poisk(d, a, b, c, d);   
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    s.erase((unique(s.begin(), s.end())), s.end());
    cout << s.size();
    for (ll i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        cout << " " << s[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, у вас переполнение ll происходит. (2*10^9)^4 (а именно такое значение у вас может получиться в check) - это уже больше 10^37, оно требует хотя бы 16-байтового целого, а long long - 8-байтовое.

Comment: Можно сделать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0 или же всё-таки попытаться решить правильно

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков а тут даже мне интересно стало: как это можно сделать "правильно"? Если не использовать заумные теоремы, то нужно использовать теорему о целых корнях, и она работает именно так, как ее описал автор вопроса. Или вы хотите решать кубическое уравнение, а потом проверять корни на целочисленность? Я честно не уверен, что это достаточно просто сделать (проверить, я имею в виду), а тем более без длинки данный способ также не работает. В общем, объясните хотя бы мне, пожалуйста

Comment: @EzikBro теорема то верная, а вот проверка check нет. Решить проблему с переполнением можно, например с помощью альтернативной формы записи.

Comment: Все дело было в переполнении. Переписал и задача прошла